# summing two columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

when I use this syntax it creates a series rather than adding a column to my new dataframe `sum`.

My code:

```
sum = data['variance'] = data.budget + data.actual
```

My dataframe `data` currently has everything except the `budget - actual` column. How do I create a `variance` column?

```
    cluster  date                  budget  actual budget - actual
0   a        2014-01-01  00:00:00  11000   10000       1000
1   a        2014-02-01  00:00:00  1200    1000
2   a        2014-03-01  00:00:00  200     100
3   b        2014-04-01  00:00:00  200     300
4   b        2014-05-01  00:00:00  400     450
5   c        2014-06-01  00:00:00  700     1000
6   c        2014-07-01  00:00:00  1200    1000
7   c        2014-08-01  00:00:00  200     100
8   c        2014-09-01  00:00:00  200     300
```

Comment: Either I can't reproduce your result or I'm not understanding you.  Are you saying that after you do this `data` does not contain a "variance" column?  Why are you assigning to two things at once?  What result do you want?

Comment: im saying If I print the result of (sum) variable, I get a series, and not a new dataframe, which has what my original dataframe (df) has, but also had a variance (budget - actual) column?

Comment: `data.budget + data.actual` gives a Series.  You assign that to `sum`, so `sum` is a series.  If you want a DataFrame, you need to create a DataFrame and then assign `data.budget + data.actual` to a column of that.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood some python syntax, the following does two assignments:

```
In [11]: a = b = 1

In [12]: a
Out[12]: 1

In [13]: b
Out[13]: 1
```

So in your code it was as if you were doing:

```
sum = df['budget'] + df['actual']  # a Series
# and
df['variance'] = df['budget'] + df['actual']  # assigned to a column
```

The latter creates a new column for df:

```
In [21]: df
Out[21]:
  cluster                 date  budget  actual
0       a  2014-01-01 00:00:00   11000   10000
1       a  2014-02-01 00:00:00    1200    1000
2       a  2014-03-01 00:00:00     200     100
3       b  2014-04-01 00:00:00     200     300
4       b  2014-05-01 00:00:00     400     450
5       c  2014-06-01 00:00:00     700    1000
6       c  2014-07-01 00:00:00    1200    1000
7       c  2014-08-01 00:00:00     200     100
8       c  2014-09-01 00:00:00     200     300

In [22]: df['variance'] = df['budget'] + df['actual']

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
  cluster                 date  budget  actual  variance
0       a  2014-01-01 00:00:00   11000   10000     21000
1       a  2014-02-01 00:00:00    1200    1000      2200
2       a  2014-03-01 00:00:00     200     100       300
3       b  2014-04-01 00:00:00     200     300       500
4       b  2014-05-01 00:00:00     400     450       850
5       c  2014-06-01 00:00:00     700    1000      1700
6       c  2014-07-01 00:00:00    1200    1000      2200
7       c  2014-08-01 00:00:00     200     100       300
8       c  2014-09-01 00:00:00     200     300       500
```

*As an aside, you shouldn't use `sum` as a variable name as the overrides the built-in sum function.*

Comment: and if I want the dataframe with the variance in it in a new dataframe? Isn't this very similar to the syntax I used, but I use dts?  data['variance'] = data.budget + data.actual

Comment: @yoshiserry As in the same DataFrame, but not changing `data`?

Comment: @yoshiserry yes, syntax for that is the same `data.budget` is the same thing as `data['budget']`.

Comment: so 1st I shouldn't use a built in variable name like sum, but what else did I need to do to get all the other original columns from my dataframe (df) into my var (variance) dataframe?

Comment: If you want to keep the initial one around then do something like `df_original = df.copy()` to start with. Assigning to a column changes the frame inplace...

Comment: Very Odd, the first time I tried it: didn't work. Now it does. So the only way to create a new dataframe (dfB) with the contents of (dfA) and a new column added, is to: 1. copy Df A, then modify Df B, adding the  new column?

Answer (score 30):

```
df['variance'] = df.loc[:,['budget','actual']].sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: And in case you have multiple columns to sum:
     df['variance'] = df.iloc[:, 1: ].sum(axis=1)

Comment: df['variance'] = df[['budget','actual']].sum(axis=1)  # looks prettier

Answer (score 3):

Same thing can be done using lambda function.
Here I am reading the data from a xlsx file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("data.xlsx", sheet_name = 4)
print df
```

Output:

```
  cluster Unnamed: 1      date  budget  actual
0       a 2014-01-01  00:00:00   11000   10000
1       a 2014-02-01  00:00:00    1200    1000
2       a 2014-03-01  00:00:00     200     100
3       b 2014-04-01  00:00:00     200     300
4       b 2014-05-01  00:00:00     400     450
5       c 2014-06-01  00:00:00     700    1000
6       c 2014-07-01  00:00:00    1200    1000
7       c 2014-08-01  00:00:00     200     100
8       c 2014-09-01  00:00:00     200     300
```

Sum two columns into 3rd new one.

```
df['variance'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['budget'] + x['actual'], axis=1)
print df
```

Output:

```
  cluster Unnamed: 1      date  budget  actual  variance
0       a 2014-01-01  00:00:00   11000   10000     21000
1       a 2014-02-01  00:00:00    1200    1000      2200
2       a 2014-03-01  00:00:00     200     100       300
3       b 2014-04-01  00:00:00     200     300       500
4       b 2014-05-01  00:00:00     400     450       850
5       c 2014-06-01  00:00:00     700    1000      1700
6       c 2014-07-01  00:00:00    1200    1000      2200
7       c 2014-08-01  00:00:00     200     100       300
8       c 2014-09-01  00:00:00     200     300       500
```

Comment: Is there an alternative when there are many columns and don't want to write `x['col1']+...+x['coln']` ?

Comment: i think this is the best solution :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the most elegant solution which follows DRY and work absolutely great.

```
dataframe_name[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']].sum(axis = 1, skipna = True)
```

Thank you.

Edit : missing brackets

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the [`.add()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) function:

```
 df.loc[:,'variance'] = df.loc[:,'budget'].add(df.loc[:,'actual'])
```

Answer (score 1):

If "budget" has any NaN values but you don't want it to sum to NaN then try:

```
def fun (b, a):
    if math.isnan(b):
        return a
    else:
        return b + a

f = np.vectorize(fun, otypes=[float])

df['variance'] = f(df['budget'], df_Lp['actual'])
```

Answer (score -1):

[`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) lets you sum and create columns right away:

```
In [12]: data.eval('variance = budget + actual', inplace=True)

In [13]: data
Out[13]: 
        cluster      date  budget  actual  variance
0 a  2014-01-01  00:00:00   11000   10000     21000
1 a  2014-02-01  00:00:00    1200    1000      2200
2 a  2014-03-01  00:00:00     200     100       300
3 b  2014-04-01  00:00:00     200     300       500
4 b  2014-05-01  00:00:00     400     450       850
5 c  2014-06-01  00:00:00     700    1000      1700
6 c  2014-07-01  00:00:00    1200    1000      2200
7 c  2014-08-01  00:00:00     200     100       300
8 c  2014-09-01  00:00:00     200     300       500
```

Since `inplace=True` you don't need to assign it back to `data`.