# summing two columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

My df looks as follows:

```
     Roll   Name    Age  Physics  English  Maths 
0     A1    Max     16     87       79      90
1     A2    Lisa    15     47       75      60
2     A3    Luna    17     83       49      95
3     A4    Ron     16     86       79      93
4     A5    Silvia  15     57       99      91
```

I'd like to add the columns Physics, English, and Maths and display the results in a separate column 'Grade'.

I've tried the code:

```
df['Physics'] + df['English'] + df['Maths']
```

But it just concatenates. I am not taught about the lambda function yet.
How do I go about this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342285/summing-two-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: By "it just concatenates" you mean you get, e.g., `877990` for the first row? If so, your columns are strings and you need to convert them to integers first. How to you read the data into `df`?

Comment: Would you like to put the total result as a column or row? My answer addresses placing a new row

Comment: @fsimonjetz yes

Comment: @DialFrost as a column

Comment: @Thakshaya there is most likely a problem in the way you read the data into the df but if you don't share how you do that we can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Grade'] = df['Physics'] + df['English'] + df['Maths']
```

it concatenates maybe your data is in `**String**` just convert into `float or integer.`
Check Data Types First by using `df.dtypes`

Comment: The data type is **integer** only

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df["total"] = df[["Physics", "English", "Maths"]].sum(axis=1)
df
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. But it still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Check Below code, Its is possible you columns are in string format, belwo will solve that:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Physics":['1','2','3'],"English":['1','2','3'],"Maths":['1','2','3']})

df['Total'] = df['Physics'].astype('int') +df['English'].astype('int') +df['Maths'].astype('int')

df
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It's working! But i am not taught of astype() yet, so I can't use it...

Comment: You don’t need to use astype(), mentioned code uses it because values are given as STRING e.g ‘1’, ‘2’ etc… If your data is integer than astype is not required.