# How to subtract 1 column from 4 columns and produce 4 new, resulting columns?

Tags: python, group-by

[image: Dataframe]

I have a dataframe as shown. I need 4 new columns [['PriceSpread_ATL', 'PriceSpread_CHI', 'PriceSpread_LA', 'PriceSpread_NY']] that are the price spreads for each market. For 'PriceSpreadATL', each cell in the column 'FarmPrice' must be subtracted from the corresponding cell in the column 'AtlantaRetail' and divided by the cell in 'FarmPrice' (ex.: (4.12 - 2.05)/2.05; (4.12 - 1.49)/1.49; (3.37 - 1.35)/1.35; (3.12 - 1.20)/ 1.20; and so on). Similarly, for 'PriceSpreadCHI', each cell in the column 'FarmPrice' must be subtracted from the corresponding cell in the column 'ChicagoRetail' and divided by the cell in 'FarmPrice', and so on for 'PriceSpread_LA' and 'PriceSpread_NY'. All the new price spread columns [['PriceSpread_ATL', 'PriceSpread_CHI', 'PriceSpread_LA', 'PriceSpread_NY']] should be appended column-wise to the dataframe. How do I carry out such an operation?

Answer (score 0):

You can try approaching it by iterating through a list of the title you want.

```
d = {'farm_p' : [2.05, 1.49, 1.35], 'A_retail': [3.39, 2.39, 5.0], 'L_retail': [4.12, 4.12, 4.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)

# Generate list for titles
header = ['A_retail', 'L_retail']

for head in header:
    # Create column & append result by row with output
    new_head = 'PriceSpread_' + head
    df[new_head] = (df[head] - df['farm_p']) / df['farm_p']
```

This should return you the additional columns you are looking for:
[image: Dataframe returned with result required]

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following, first the general idea, then an example.

```
df["new_col"] = (df["some_col"] - df["another_col"]) / df["whatever_col"]
```

In your case let's do the following.

```
df["NewLosAngelesRetail"] = (df["LosAngelesRetail"] - df["FarmPrice"]) / df["FarmPrice"]
```

Now you can do the same with other columns, here is a link with a similar question [Sum DataFrame cols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22342285/summing-two-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe).

Be careful you have NaNs [Fillnans docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Comment: Thank you! But is there a way of doing so perhaps in a single line? I was thinking something like (df.iloc[:, 3:6] - df.iloc[:, 2]) / df.iloc[:, 2] but this doesn't work.